# Как изменить значение атрибута при клике на список?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как при клике на .select__option передавать input и классу total значение атрибута data-price-class? Спасибо

```js
function select() {
    const optionMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.select__menu');

    optionMenus.forEach(optionMenu => {
        const selectBtn = optionMenu.querySelector('.select__btn');
        const options = optionMenu.querySelectorAll('.select__option');
        const sBtntext = optionMenu.querySelector('.select__input');

        if (optionMenu) {
            selectBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                let elem_active = optionMenu.classList.contains("_active")
                optionMenus.forEach(opt => {
                    opt.classList.remove('_active');
                })
                optionMenu.classList.toggle("_active", !elem_active)
            });

            options.forEach(option => {
                option.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    if (e.target.classList.contains('.select__option-text') != null) {
                        sBtntext.value = e.target.innerText;
                    };
                    options.forEach(el => { el.classList.remove('_active'); });
                    option.classList.add("_active");
                    optionMenu.classList.remove("_active")
                });
            });
            window.addEventListener('click', e => {
                const target = e.target
                if (!target.closest('.select__options') && !target.closest('.select__menu')) {
                    optionMenu.classList.remove("_active")
                }
            })

        }
    })
}

select()
```

```css
.select {
     position: relative;
}
 .select__menu {
     position: relative;
}
 .select__menu._active .select__icon {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
 .select__menu._active .select__body {
     display: block;
}
 .select__menu._active .select__input {
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
 .select__btn {
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .select__input {
     pointer-events: none;
     width: 100%;
     background: #f6f5f1;
     border: 1px solid #e8e6e1;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 11px 35px 11px 22px;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 .select__input::placeholder {
     color: #111;
}
 .select__icon {
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: 17px;
     right: 17px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
 .select__body {
     outline: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 5;
}
 .select__options {
     max-height: 100px;
     background: #fff;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e6e1;
     border-left: 1px solid #e8e6e1;
     border-right: 1px solid #e8e6e1;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
     overflow: auto;
     -ms-overflow-style: none;
     scrollbar-width: none;
}
 .select__options::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
}
 .select__option {
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 5px 22px 5px 22px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
     display: block;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 16px;
}
 .select__option:hover {
     background: #f6f5f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="select__menu">
  <div class="select__btn">
    <div class="select__btntext">
      <input data-price-class="1000" data-required id="number_3" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="form[]" value="5-7" placeholder="5-7" value class="select__input">
    </div>
    <div class="select__icon _icon-arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="select__body">
    <div class="select__options">
      <div data-price-class="1000"  class="select__option">
        <div class="select__option-text">5-7</div>
      </div>
      <div  data-price-class="2000" class="select__option">
        <div class="select__option-text">8-9</div>
      </div>
      <div  data-price-class="3000" class="select__option">
        <div class="select__option-text">10-11</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="total">0</div>
```